# First fundamental theorem of calculus where the bounds are not 0 to x.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $F(x) = \int_{3x+8}^{x^{2}+5x+1}\csc^{2}\left(t\right)dt$. How would one find $F'(x)$ using the first fundamental theorem of calculus? I am aware of how to do this when the bounds are 0 to f(x) through use of chain rule, but I don't know how to do this when the first bound is not 0.

Comment: To see how it works, divide the interval into a sum of two integrals, each of which has a constant limit; and use the Chain Rule on the other limit.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\int_a^bf(x) dx=\int_a^0f(x) dx+\int_0^bf(x) dx=\int_0^bf(x) dx-\int_0^af(x) dx$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about splitting the bounds/integral, but I can see how that works.